# rails create action with ajax without form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having a post form used to create a post it works fine as it is not much difficult.

What is need is before inserting title,content i need a `posts id` so that i can do much more processes.

So i decided to create a `light box(contains no form)` which lists all category and sub-category. onclicking the category i need to perform ajax request to create a record by inserting only category in the table.

This is my jquery code

```
    $('.selection').click(function(){
$('#category_id').val(category_id);
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/posts.json',
        dataType: 'json'
        })
    })
```

;

This is my create action

```
def create
    unless post_params.nil?
        @post = Post.new(post_params)
        if @post.save
            flash[:success] = 'Post added successfully'
            redirect_to action: :new
        else
            flash[:error] = 'Post cannot add. Please try again after some time'
            redirect_to action: :new
        end
    end

  end
```

How can i modify above action crate for ajax submit. Can anyone please help.

Comment: how can you create category with this code of create action, could you explain?

Comment: No data sent in Ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just forgot to send data in your Ajax Call.
You should try:

```
    $('.selection').click(function(){
      $('#category_id').val(category_id);
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/posts.json',
        dataType: 'json'
        data: {
         id: the_id,
         other_param: the_other_param
        }
      })
    })
```

Hope it will help you!